# Lenovo G510, beep sound 6-2-2. No bootable device found

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair, system-sounds, water-damage

I spilled water on the laptop Lenovo G510. The laptop automatically shut itself down and I plugged out all the connections to it thereafter. Then I used hair dryer to dry everything for an hour. Also, I opened the laptop and disconnected everything inside ... motherboard connections etc. After I was done , I pressed power button and everything worked just fine  but later in the night , I switched it on again and now it gives beep sound , 6 small beeps ...then 2 small beeps ...again 2 small beeps and then it repeats it. Display shows no bootable device .

Comment: One hour wasn't enough, should have left it open to dry for many hours. The computer needs a repair-shop.

Answer (score 1):

With just the information you've provided, we cannot give you an exact answer as to what is wrong. However, just based on the information you've given, there is a finite number of things that could possibly be wrong. Including, but not necessarily limited to:

1. **There is some residual water that is causing intermittent issues.** Just to be on the safe side, leave the computer unplugged for the next 24 hours and place it in a dry area to be sure that no more water is left before you try to power it on again.
2. **When you disassembled the laptop, you may not have fully secured a cable (or multiple cables) on the main board and/or the hard disk/SSD.** This would result in a "No Bootable Device" message like you describe. The solution here would be to disassemble the machine again and confirm that all connectors to the main board and the hard disk/SSD are secure and fully inserted.
3. **There may be permanent water damage.** While it's not what you want to hear, the water may have permanently damaged some components in the machine.

Unfortunately, without further testing and back-and-forth discussion, it will be impossible for us to give you a proper diagnosis. Your best bet will be to take the machine to a reputable individual or shop for repairs if you wait another 24 hours for the machine to dry and it still is inoperable.

Comment: "Water damage" =any-of=> Liquid created a short circuit which "fried" a component. The liquid contained something that created a conducting surface between component pins. Liquid actually entered into a component and created a problem. GENERALLY: Water does not conduct, there has to be something in it that allows current to travel through it - generally "ions".